# Adding content to react elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to react.js and I have heard that this js library reacts badly to anything that modifies it's component structure. 
        Is there any specific procedure to add content into react elements using Jquery. For example, if we want to add content into react's div field, can we directly use Jquery append method to insert text to that div or is there any other way to implement things?.

Comment: Can you add example code of what you have tried so far? Questions on StackOverflow need to be specific so people can more easily understand the problem and offer relevant help.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you either use a traditional approach, or you ditch jQuery and use react and this means using the react rendering tree, probably build tasks, client-side router/SPA.

You should not modify the DOM generated by react components from outside it since it maintains an internal state and a virtual DOM that would become out of sync. You either use one ecosystem or another; they are two very different approaches to writing a website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce react on a small part of the website first, I would suggest to gather all your data with jquery and then transmit the data into the react component.

Roughly

```
// gather data with jquery or whatever
var data_array = gatherData();

ReactDOM.render(<MyCustomComponent data={data_array}/>, $('#my-react-root')[0])
```

Rendering changes during runtime can be managed the same way. Just gather the data again and change the state of the react component accordingly.

If you don't want to extract the data or the html is to complex, you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to just path a plain text html string.

From the docs:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: getMarkup()}} />
```

Best wishes
Andreas